# C extra # lines after preprocessing part

Tags: c

I am learning part by part how c code gets compiled into an executable file
and currently analysing the preprocessing stage.

What interests me is the extra lines starting with # symbol that appear in the preprocessed file.

For example, file "unpreprocessed.c":

```
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Gets preprocessed into a file "preprocessed.c":

```
# 1 "unpreprocessed.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "unpreprocessed.c"
int main(void) {
     return 0;
}
```

after running linux command:

```
gcc -E unpreprocessed.c >preprocessed.c
```

Could someone explain what those extra lines (e.g # 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4) mean?

Note that the preprocessed file gets compiled successfully into
an executable file by running the command

```
gcc preprocessed.c
```

(so successfully passes again the preprocessing as well as other parts)

Also, if I try to preprocess the preprocessed file again, I will get those
lines copied twice with the exception that

```
# 1 "unpreprocessed.c"
```

changes to

```
# 1 "preprocessed.c"
```

Comment: These are file names and line numbers that are read by the compiler. Normally you get a lot of these when you use `#include` directives (try `#include stdio.h` and see), but even without any `#include`s the compiler needs to look aside here and there. `"<built-in>"` and `"<command-line>"` are not real file names but they act in a similar way and so are included in the output.

Comment: Thanks for showing a duplicate question. So on a high level, these lines help compiler to print error messages, showing which line in the code is wrong?

Comment: That's correct. These lines also help generate correct debug information.